# How can is select XML tag that contains specific XML tag with specific text inside using regual expressions?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have XML text. In that XML text I have tags named `<pskc:KeyPackage>` this tag may or may not contain different tags and one of that tag may be `<pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>`. With regular expressions i want to select all `<pskc:KeyPackage>` tags, which contain `<pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>` tag. How can i accomplish this?

please see regex on flowing link: https://regex101.com/r/7HICeu/2

This is my sample input:

```
<pskc:KeyPackage>  

 <testTag>val1</testTag>

  <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  <testTag2>val2</testTag2>

</pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>2</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>3</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>2</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>3</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>2</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>3</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>2</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>3</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>2</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>3</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
```

i want to mach following tags:

```
<pskc:KeyPackage>  

 <testTag>val1</testTag>

  <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  <testTag2>val2</testTag2>

</pskc:KeyPackage>
```

and i also want to match each tag that look like this:

```
  <pskc:KeyPackage>

      <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  </pskc:KeyPackage>
```

I want to say again that `<pskc:KeyPackage>` tag will contain many different tags, like it does in following example:

```
<pskc:KeyPackage>  

 <testTag>val1</testTag>

  <pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>

  <testTag2>val2</testTag2>

</pskc:KeyPackage>
```

I want to mach the whole `<pskc:KeyPackage>` tag only if it contains `<pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>`. How can i accomplish this?

P.S. I have also tried many different regex-es, on of them is following regex: `<pskc:KeyPackage>[\s\S]*<pskc:IssueNo>1<\/pskc:IssueNo>[\s\S]*<pskc:KeyPackage>` but it maches whole xml string.

Thank you

Comment: Can you copy the example input in the question e write what you want to match?

Comment: Why would you want to do this with regex? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/317052) A simple xpath could be used: `//pskc:KeyPackage[pskc:IssueNo='1']`

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili, I think I have the regex you are looking for in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231964/5825294).

Comment: @DanielHaley thanks for info, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This works](https://regex101.com/r/qWmT4F/1):

```
/<pskc:KeyPackage>((?!<\/pskc:KeyPackage>).)*<pskc:IssueNo>1<\/pskc:IssueNo>.*?<\/pskc:KeyPackage>/gs
```

(I don't know all regex flavors, but it looks like this works for Perl, JS, and Python.)

How it works:

- it matches `<pskc:KeyPackage>`,
- followed by any amount (the first `*`) of any characters (the first `.`) including newlines (the `s` flag), each of which matches where `</pskc:KeyPackage>` does **not** match (`(?!…)`),
- followed by `<pskc:IssueNo>1</pskc:IssueNo>`.
- Then it also matches up the the closest (`.*?`) closing `</pskc:KeyPackage>`.

Other two details:

- `/`s need to be escaped, `\/`,
- depending on your application, you might want to use non-capturing parentheses for the first group (change the first `(` to `(?:`), whose sole purpose is to let you apply the first `*` to it.

Comment: I have learned new things about regular expressions and better understand them now thanks to this answer